# Is there any way in dss to read data from multiple sheet of single excel and insert those data into multiple tables of database using wso2 6.4.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am new to wso2 6.4.0 dss, i have to do retrieve the data from multiple sheets of single excel file and insert those data into multiple tables. Please help me to do this. just guide me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need sophisticated logic to implement. Excel files may be a source of data. First of all how wsodss does know about a moment when it must start read excel? It sounds like wsoesb job, which supports a virtual file-system, and can truck directory and generate an event if there are any changes.

Why don't you use wsoesb to read sheet by sheet and insert data? 
It provides the necessary tools (mediators) to execute.

Anyway, it does look like a ETL job.

Comment: Hi.,i am fine with wso esb proxy services, but using proxy needs to write more files, cant insert directly from excel to database. that's what i choosed wso2 dss.

Comment: is it possible to do this with wso2 dss option?

Comment: Well, wsoesb can write to the database first all "DbReport" but I am sure is it designed to write a massive amount of data. Best option is to make dss service to write data and esb service to read data from excel and send it to dss. They even can coexist in the same runtime and use local calls.

Comment: Fine, Could you please share some samples like how to pass esb output to dss.